# Having problems with my recursive function

Tags: c, string, recursion, strcmp

I don't understand why it stops right after it reaches the line " if(strcmp(next,str2) == 0) return; " 

for now I commented out the %.*s print line just so I can fully print the two strings that are being compared before it reaches the if statement so the 5 is irrelevant in my example input.

when I print the two strings "next" and "str2", the following shows
[image]

I can see the string "ABC DEF" is not the same as "BC DEFA" but it seems it satisfies the if statement because it stops the marquee function. When I comment out the if statement, it'll go through infinite recursion. 
 Maybe it is same I thought so I printed the strcmp program of the two strings
[image]
 It shows strcmp is -1, which isn't 0

Can someone enlighten me? Maybe I am just missing something simple or is there a better way to break out of my recursion once next is equal to str2.

edit: I put in the rotate function

```
int main(){

    int n,i,signlength;
    char sign[100]; //max 99 letters

    //get number of cases
    scanf("%d",&n);

    //process each case
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){

        //ignore rest of line \n
        char ic;
        while ( (ic = getc(stdin)) != EOF && ic != '\n');
        //take in sign string and length of sign
        gets(sign);
        scanf("%d",&signlength);

        if(signlength >= strlen(sign))
                printf("[%-*s]\n",signlength,sign);

        if(signlength < strlen(sign)){

                printf("%s\n",sign);
                //printf("[%.*s]\n",signlength,sign);
                marquee(sign,signlength,sign);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

char* marquee(char* str, int size, char* str2){

    char* next = rotate(str);

    printf("%s\n",next);
    //printf("[%.*s]\n",size,next);
    if(strcmp(next,str2) == 0)
        return;

        return marquee(next,size,str2);

}

void swap(char* a, char* b){

    char temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void reverse(char* array, int size){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size/2;i++)
        swap(array + i, array + (size-i-1));
}

char* rotate(char* str){

    reverse(str +1, strlen(str) -1);
    reverse(str, strlen(str));

    return str;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sur that your function `marquee` can compile in this state... Are you sure of what you are testing?

Comment: Not testing the return value from `scanf` is always a recipe for surprises. As is using the deprecated gets() function. Use fgets instead. Oh, and what do think happens when you `return;` from a function returning a `char *`?

Comment: @purplepsycho , No I'm not sure. I am new to C and unfamiliar with how meshes together when passing through functions and such so my best bet is just printing everything lol

Comment: Instead of just printing `next`, print both `next` and `str`.  I suspect your rotate function may be modifying `str` so that both `next` and `str` end up rotated.  If you show the code for `rotate`, I'll be able to tell you.

Comment: @Jens , I thought a blank return would just go back to main, but by your wording I have feeling that is not it. but lemme try using fgets

Comment: Don't post images of text! Paste the text instead.

Comment: @Olaf , oh okay. sorry

Comment: @Tom Karzes, I put in those functions for you

Comment: Ok, it's exactly what I suggested above.  I posted an answer that will solve this specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rotate and reverse functions both operate on your character array in-place.  In fact, if you look at `rotate`, you can see it always returns `str`.  So when you do:

```
char* next = rotate(str);
```

All it's doing it rotating `str` in-place and then returning `str`.  After the call, `next` has the same value as `str`, and the original contents of `str` are no longer available.

If you want to preserve `str`, just make a copy of it.  For instance, you could do:

```
char* next = rotate(strdup(str));
```

That will first copy `str`, then call `rotate` which will destructively modify the copy, leaving `str` unchanged.

Comment: oh ! asdfghjkl. 
Thank you! when you say destrutively, should I make my changes to the str more efficient ?

Comment: No, it just means it overwrites the string it operates on, effectively destroying it in the process.  Sometimes that's ok, but in this case it wasn't.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that you call `marquee()` with `str` and `str2` being the same pointer. When you `rotate(str)` this also "does the same" to `str2` (since they point to the same memory.) This likely does not do what you think it should.

And by all means, **turn on ALL the warnings of your compiler** and it catches the `return;` in `marquee()` for free.

Comment: ohh, I would like str2 to stay the same, so I should declare another variable maybe? That will hold the original. so like Original = str2?

Comment: @Hispazn No, that would only create a third pointer. You need to **copy the data that the string points to**. I.e. use a second array of char, or malloc some memory and copy the old to the new memory.